# Choose a certain version of Visual Studio's command line toolkit and compile files against a certain version of a C++ run-time environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cl

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Trying to compile a package using certain version of the C++ toolkit and to compile against a certain version a c++ run-time environment.

In my case that would mean the latest toolkit against the latest c++ run-time environment libraries.

How do I make this happen? I tried to use `/std:c++17` or `/std:latest` but this results in a build compiled against `vc140.dll`.

The documentation of neither `cl.exe` nor `link.exe` gives any kind of a hint.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: "toolkit" does not mean anything.  It *resembles* "toolset".  The set of build tools, cl.exe is part of it.  vc141.dll does not mean anything.  It *resembles* vcruntime140.dll, there is no 141 version of that DLL.  They did not create a new version of that runtime DLL for VS2017, yay.  There is no indication that you have a problem.

Comment: There was a confusion in my question indeed. thank you for pointing out. I've modified my question. What i meant was how to choose the version of c++ standard libraries to compile against. I have left the part regarding toolkit version due to already proposed answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties UI you can set platform Toolset on the "General" page.

For v140 the resulting command lines start:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe

but for v141 they start:-

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe

You can read the command line for yourself if you set the build output to diagnostic (via Tools->Options->Build and Run).

Comment: it's a mistake on my side. can't modify it yet due to some time-lock.

Comment: and also there was a confusion in my question itself; it is not about the version of the toolkit; but the version of desired c++ run-time environment.

Comment: @Vega4 please don't downvote answers for not using information you didn't put in the question.

Comment: The general technique of finding a gui setting that does what you want and seeing what that does to the command line may still be of use, In this case we see it actually changes the location of the cl.exe being called. That folder happens to contain a vcruntime140.dll (and no 141)

Answer (score 0):

You can set them here using the dropdown

```
(project properties)
(configuration properties)
(general)
(platform toolset)
```

Comment: The question is regarding command line build without any project file.

Comment: Interesting.  I see the ambiguity.  You should make it clear in the question before it gets closed for real.